# Azure - copy files from VM to a storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I have prepared a script for executing .ps1 script on a Windows in Azure. Powershell script is stored on a storage account. Script output is directed to a local C:\ drive on a Windows VM. In order to run a script on a VM i am using Custom Script Extension, extract from my code below. Question is, how can I copy received `output.csv` from my `C:\` drive on a Windows VM to a storage account?

```
##Storage Account credentials
$StorageAccountName = (Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'xxx').UserName
$StorageAccountKey = (Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'xxx').GetNetworkCredential().Password

$Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$CSEName = ((Get-AzureRmVm -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $VM | 
Where-Object {$_.Extensions.VirtualMachineExtensionType -eq "CustomScriptExtension"}).Extensions | 
Where-Object {$_.VirtualMachineExtensionType -eq "CustomScriptExtension"}).Name

write-output "CSE Name: $CSEName"

Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
    -VMName $VM `
    -FileName $psfilename `
    -ContainerName $ContainerName `
    -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName `
    -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey `
    -Run $psfilename `
    -Location "North Europe"`
    -Name $CSEName

$LogFilePath = "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Output.csv"
```

Comment: As a workaround, you can use the Azure File Share for your storage account and map it in your script with something like that: `net use x: <azure-storage-account.file.core.windows.net\output> /u:<azure-storage-account-name> <azure-storage-account-primary-key>`

Answer (score -1):

**Note:** I re-edited my entire Ansewr

if I understand your script correctly, you are using it for internal usage.
in that case, the solution is very simple.
as you have all the information on the source and destination, all you need is to connect them to the [proper Blob to Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-3.1.0).

- You will need either a Storage Account Access-Key (easy to get/ use but less secure)
- or a SAS with at least the following Privileges =Read, wright, List. (a bit harder to configure but more secure)

here is an example using Storage Account Access-Key:

```
$ResourceGroupName = "Resource-Group"
$storageAccountName = "Storge account"
#full path to the file
$localPath = "C:\test\vm01.5f9e0fc2-cf60-444f-9cba-61c6f66b6373.serialconsole.log"
#blob container name
$storageContainerName = "test"
#Blob name (the name of the file in after the transfer)
$BlobName = "destFileName.log"


#getting the SA Key
$SAkey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -AccountName $storageAccountName).Value[0]
#getting Storage account context
$destinationContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $SAkey
#copy the file
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $localPath -Container $storageContainerName -Blob $BlobName -Context $destinationContext
```

the script is working if your connected to azure, if not, you can pass a SAS URL instedof the `$SAkey` and it will work the same.
to run it, just add at the end of your ps1 script.

Comment: Pls provide more detalis, f.e. task 1., What ps1 script to copy data??